# Inserting a list/vector of parameters into a function

Tags: r, function, vector

I need to repeat a function many times, with differing parameters held constant across iterations.  To accomplish this, I would like to create a list (or vector) of parameters, and then insert that list into the function.

For example:

```
q<-c("l,a,b,s")

genericfunction<-function(q){
}
```

The equivalent code would of course be

```
genericfunction<-function(l,a,b,s){
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it depends greatly on what you're doing with the parameters... you can certainly pass a list and parse it once in the function.  Please expand on the contents of your `generic_function`.

Comment: It sounds like `mapply` is well suited to your conundrum.

Comment: Vote to close unless your question is updated to have a more specific reproducible example of the behavior you want.

Comment: What problem have you encountered? This isn't http://make-this-for-me-plz.com

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel your link doesn't work for me.

Comment: @agstudy: I'm sure it's just overloaded at the moment due to high demand.

Comment: Will a `list(l=something, a=somethingelse, b=anotherthing, s=lastthing)` into your function `genericfunction(l, a, b, s)` do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're after `do.call`.

```
genericfunction <- function(l, a, b, s){
  l+a+b+s
}

args <- list(l=1, a=3, b=345, s=-4)

do.call(genericfunction, args)
[1] 345
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the get() and assign() functions - they may accomplish what you're after. Could you expand your example?